# VB Script Path Not found searching remote folder

Tags: vbscript

I need to both upload files to and download files from an FTP site using vbscript. In both cases I am searching in a particular folder for files using GetFolder.files then either uploading or downloading them if files are present. My upload script below has been tested and uploads files properly the moved them to a processed folder:

```
Dim oFtp
Dim oFso

oFtp.Protocol = "SFTP"
oFtp.Host = "ftp2.HostName.com"
oFtp.Login = "hftest"
oFtp.Password = "********"
oFtp.UseProxy = "BOTH"
oFtp.Port = "2022"
oFtp.Connect

oFtp.LocalFolder = "C:\LocalFolder\Files"
oFtp.RemoteFolder = "RemoteFolder/Upload" 

For Each oFile In oFso.GetFolder(oFtp.LocalFolder).Files
    If (UCase(oFso.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "BIF") Then

       oFtp.Upload oFile.Name 
       If UCase(oFtp.Status) = "FINISHED" Then
          oFso.MoveFile oFtp.LocalFolder + "\" + oFile.Name, oFtp.LocalFolder + "\Processed\"
       Else
          Quit(1)
       End If   
    End If
Next
```

I figured since this works I could just reverse the process for the download script by using GetFolder.files from the remote side so I can download files if they are present. I get the "Path Not found" error on the line with the For loop. I have confirmed the remote folder exists by manually going to it via FTP. I have confirmed that folder has full rights on the FTP site and I have had some in company vb script experts look at my script and no one can tell me what is wrong.

```
Dim oFtp
Dim oFso

oFtp.Protocol = "SFTP"
oFtp.Host = "ftp2.HostName.com"
oFtp.Login = "hftest"
oFtp.Password = "********"
oFtp.UseProxy = "BOTH"
oFtp.Port = "2022"
oFtp.Connect

oFtp.LocalFolder = "C:\LocalFolder\Payments"
oFtp.RemoteFolder = "RemoteFolder/Payments" 

For Each oFile In oFso.GetFolder(oFtp.RemoteFolder).Files
    oFtp.Download oFile.Name 
    If UCase(oFtp.Status) = "FINISHED" Then
       oFtp.DeleteFile(oFtp.RemoteFolder + "/" + oFile.Name)
    Else
      Quit
   End If   
Next
```

I am sure the syntax is not 100% perfect as I am learning vb script on the fly because this is a new project for our current flag ship application.